# Is the con[census] to burninate [census]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We forgot to fill out our [census](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/census) (currently 155 questions, no tag wiki).

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, most of the questions are actually about data processing and/or querying, not censuses.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No, censuses are not inherently on-topic. As a concept, they are more appropriate on Politics.SE, with a few possible questions on Law.SE on potential penalties for noncompliance with census requirements and theoretical authority for various census-taking activities performed by certain government agencies.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, it is much more helpful to tag with the specific database, file format, API, and/or type of processing desired (sort, aggregate, search, update, detransmogrify, etc.) rather than the business purpose of the data.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Not really, there are many different censuses in the world that use different data standards. Learning about one is not going to tell you much, if anything, about another that is technical in nature. Someone who is an expert in running `GROUP BY` queries on race from official US government records is not necessarily going to know anything about the data format of the Guatemalan census or how to find the number of dentists per capita based on that government's API.

We could *potentially* have tags for specific census data sources or formats, such as:

[us-census](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/us-census)

[canadian-census](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canadian-census)

[ruritanian-census](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruritanian-census)

[wakandan-census-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wakandan-census-2018)

Comment: Nah, no tags about data sources. Questions should include a description of the source on the post itself. I don't need to know what is the source to answer how many stdev is a number from the median.

Comment: Could also be confused with census badge

Comment: Is the con[census] to burniate [census]?

Comment: I thought this was about the badge, since a bunch of them are being awarded right now. The tag doesn't strike me as useful.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Same, this is probably the reason why this question is hot on meta, right now.

Comment: Given that completing the (on-going at the time of writing) 2021 Developer Survey can result in the Cencus badge being awarded, perhaps make the distinction clear in your question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen isn't the [tag] moniker enough?

Comment: Only way this is a good tag is if there is a specific API for a specific census providor (for example if the US Census Bureau has an [API](https://www.census.gov/data/developers.html), so a programming question about using that API would be on-topic.  But the tag should be explicit that it is about the API and not just a question about the census itself

Comment: The ONLY reason that I visited this page was because I thought it was about the recent survey.

Comment: @psubsee2003 and even then it's not specific enough. If several org provide census data via API, which one the [census] tag refers to?

Comment: Could the term census refer to something more than a government counting people? I don't know much about data science, but it wouldn't surprise me if census could be a term for some statistic or statistic method, which would be more on topic.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to make it a synonym of the best tag for sample statistics?

Comment: @Braiam agreed.  I was more pointing out a tag that explicitly points out it is about a specific API would be on topic (such as [tag:us-census-api] would be better and a generic census tag should go away

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a rather classic Meta tag. It doesn't appear to take any special programming expertise to process census data in particular (vs. other kinds of survey data), so I really don't see how this tag is helpful - it's just adding unnecessary context information that doesn't really help people find questions to answer.

I say we burninate it.